# linker command failed with exit code 1 (MAC MPI)

Tags: c++, mpi

I am trying to run a simple MPI code as I am learning MPI. I am using ECLIPSE PTP platform for c++ for compiling. In linux it is working fine. Here is the code.

```
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

int num_procs;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&num_procs);

int rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

if(rank == 0){
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
}
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
```

I'm getting this error:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_MPI_Comm_rank", referenced from:
_main in main.o
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mpi_test] Error 1

Comment: More details needed - I just installed eclipse ptp and brew installed open-mpi and a hello world mpi program just fell out. You are compiling using `mpicc`, and not some hand-crafted makefile?

Comment: The error message suggests `_MPI_Comm_size` was found and that is weird. Dud you truncate the error log ?

Comment: MPI_Comm_size not found. I only showed one error. All other error similar to that "_MPI_Comm_rank", referenced from ....

Comment: Which linker is eclipse using ? It should be `mpicxx` instead of `g++`

Comment: I am using mpic++. I am providing mpic++ manually